# birthday paradox Loop program with user input

Tags: python

I am making a birthday paradox program and it is pretty much completed

```
import random

duplicateNumber=0

def has_duplicates(listToCheck):
    number_set = set(listToCheck)

    if len(number_set) is not len(listToCheck):
        return True
    else:
        return False 

for i in range(0,1000):
    birthdayList=[]

    for j in range(0,23):  
        birthday=random.randint(1,365)
        birthdayList.append(birthday)

    x = has_duplicates(birthdayList)

    if x==True:
        duplicateNumber+=1

print ("after 1000 simulations with 23 students there were", duplicateNumber,"simulations with at least one match")
```

I want to improve my code by asking the user to keep repeating the code until they want it to terminate it. E.g The code will give the output and then ask the user if they want to run it again. If the input, for example, is "yes" the code will run again then give the output again but this time it will most likely have a different  duplicatenumber value. Then the process will repeat again and again until the user inputs 'no' then the program will end

Answer (score 0):

Change part of your code to -

```
import random

duplicateNumber=0

def has_duplicates(listToCheck):
    number_set = set(listToCheck)

    if len(number_set) is not len(listToCheck):
        return True
    else:
        return False 
i=0
while True:
    if i>0:
        prompt = raw_input('Do you wish to continue?')
        if prompt.lower() == 'no':
            break
    birthdayList=[]

    for j in range(0,23):  
        birthday=random.randint(1,365)
        birthdayList.append(birthday)

    x = has_duplicates(birthdayList)

    if x==True:
        duplicateNumber+=1
    i += 1

print ("after ", i," simulations with 23 students there were", duplicateNumber,"simulations with at least one match")
```

Loops through an infinite loop constantly asking the user if he wishes to continue. Moment he says no, breaks out of the loop and prints the stats

Comment: Excuse me, where did you exactly change my code? I tried putting in your changes and I can't seem to get it to work. Can you please post the whole code. Thank you.

Comment: This wasn't what I was really asking for but thank you for trying. I'll be more specific in my question